# How to use styling in React fluentui with child components

Tags: fluent-ui, fluentui-react

How do you create components with React fluentui and apply styling to root and child components?

Comment: Fluent usually allows you to do that via `styles` prop or custom `onRender` function. Can you make your question more specific like what components exactly you would want to style?

Comment: Hi @MartinT I am trying build custom component in flentui using Stack and StackItem component. I need to set styles for children inside the Stack component using class name. I used to handle styling using styled-components earlier. Can you please tell me how can that be done in fluentui?

Comment: For custom components (not-dependend on Fluent) you are free to use whatever styling you wish - styled components for example. If you want to restyle existing Fluent components on the other hand, Fluent uses CSS-in-JS. For a more concrete help, you will have to provide some code samples.

Comment: Hi @MartinT

I tried below styling code: 

`const styles = {
  root: { /* styles */ },
  child1: { /* styles */ },
  child2: { /* styles */ }
  subComponentStyles: {
    subComponent: {
      root: { /* styles */ },
      child1: { /* styles */ },
    }
  }
}`

Can you please tell me how to add it to child components. CSS code I add inside child1 and child2 doesn't apply to children.

For component I am using:

`<Stack styles={styles }>
<StackItem>
Hello
</StackItem>
</Stack>`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.